# Unknown parent error in Mercurial but no error in verify

Tags: mercurial

We have too large Mercurial repo's in which following error has occured few times during a year when trying to clone:

```
$ hg clone --rev develop --noupdate http://url.to.repository
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: data/.../Result.Database.nuspec.i@03b180f4076b: unknown parent!
```

All goes well if I don't specify a revision in clone command.

Hg verify doesn't show any error:

```
$ hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
3427 files, 913 changesets, 5406 total revisions
```

How can I fix this error?

What is causing this error? I would like to fix the root cause to prevent this happening anymore in future.

Comment: Hg version in server is 3.7.3 and in my machine 3.8.4.

Comment: assuming your repo is a mercurial forest, the problem might be caused by a mismatch between .hgsubstate file and one of the subrepositories it is pointing to. Try editing .hgsubstate.

Comment: We are not using subreposittories and there isn't any .hgsubstate file.